# Refresh Standard Related list(s) from Custom Component in Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, aura

Is it possible to refresh a standard related list (Contact) from a component that lives on the same page?  I have a custom component that imports a contact from an external system and I need the "Contact" related list to refresh in the action's callback.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried [force:refreshView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm)?

Comment: Perfect.  If you want to actually reply as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After modifying data, you should tell the standard components to refresh the data. You do this by using [force:refreshView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:refreshView/documentation). This is typically done using the following code:

```
$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
```

This works in Lightning Experience, Salesforce1, and Communities that use Lightning.

Comment: @manza auradocs is the best reference. If for some reason it's not working, consider submitting a case to support. It might a permissions issue, you might need to clear your cache, or it could be something else. Many of the methods in $A are also in the Lightning Component Developer Guide, but they're not in any consolidated form.

Comment: this would not work if "Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components and Aura components" is enabled under the session setting